# Seen by stopped working

Tags: facebook, windows

The seen by function has suddenly stopped working in my private facebook group and also when I view other posts.  If I view the same things from a different profile it works.  I've checked both sets of settings and both are set identically so I have no idea why its stopped working for one profile and not another or how to fix it.  My group has only 21 members so it shouldn't be hidden.  Has anyone any ideas how I can fix this?  I use Windows 10 on one machine and Windows 11 on another and the same thing happens on both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting-like questions are off-topic in Web Applications SE. P.S. Try using your web browser in private / incognito mode with all the extensions disabled.